# Time validation in TextBox. Validating a textbox for some regular expression

Tags: c#, wpf

I've to make a textbox(WPF) for entering time with validation.
I want to enter a regular expression validation for time (6:12 am).

Comment: Please be more specific. Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: I've a text box in which user can input time like 6:00 am or user can give time in minutes e.g. 123 > which will be converted in time format using converter. But i want to give validation on user input. I think using a regular expression would help. Still looking for a perfect solution. I've error template implemented so no help regarding how to throw error required.

Comment: If there are multiple formats, people would probably enter time in formats they are comfortable with (123 could be 1:23 am or 2:03). Are you limiting the formats in which user can enter time?

Comment: Yes. i'm limiting them to input 1:23 instead of 123.

Comment: Your comments are contradictory to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errors.aspx for handling validation errors in controls

Else you can implement [IDataErrorInfo](http://www.codegod.de/webappcodegod/wpf-idataerrorinfo-and-databinding-AID416.aspx) in your viewmodel so that the Validation is embedded to your data itself.

Comment: Hands down, no doubt this is best answer by far.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one :

```
class TimeTextBox : TextBox
{
    public Boolean IsProperTime { get; set; }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime time;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) || !DateTime.TryParse(Text, out time))
        {
            IsProperTime = false;
        }
        else
        {
            IsProperTime = true;
        }

        UpdateVisual();

        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }

    private void UpdateVisual()
    {
        if (!IsProperTime)
        {
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
        }
        else
        {
            ClearValue(BorderBrushProperty);
            ClearValue(BorderThicknessProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the time parsing logic in there.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not the right choice here.  You ultimate do need to convert a string to a date or time.  Use DateTime.TryParse() so you are always sure that if the validation allows it then the conversion will work as well.